# Enumerating m-tuples of Integers Subject to Implication Constraints

Tags: algorithm, integer, constraints, enumeration, tuples

How do I enumerate all m-tuples of nonnegative integers (a[1],...,a[m]) subject to the following constraints?

1. For each i in {1,...,m}, there is a number n[i] >= 0 such that a[i] <= n[i].
2. For each ordered pair (i,j) with i,j in {1,...,m}, there are numbers c[i][j], d[i][j] >= 0 such that:

   if a[i] > c[i][j], then a[j] <= d[i][j].
3. c[i][j] = c[j][i].

So far, I have come up with the following solution.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?  I am programming in C or C++.

```
for a[1]=0,...,n[1] do 
{
    for j=2,...,m do
    {
        if a[1] > c[1][j] then n[j]:=min{n[j],d[1][j]}
                          else n[j]:=n[j]
    }
    for a[2]=0,...,n[2] do 
    {
        for j=3,...,m do
        {
            if a[2] > c[2][j] then n[j]:=min{n[j],d[2][j]}
                              else n[j]:=n[j]
        }
        for a[3]=0,...,n[3] do
        {
            .
            .
            .
            for a[m]=0,...,n[m] do
            {
                print (a[1],...,a[m])
            }
        }...}}
```

I see one major inefficiency in this algorithm.  To see it, take m=2 for simplicity.  Say n[1] = n[2] = 2 and c[i][j] = d[i][j] = 0 for all i,j.  Now let's go through the algorithm.

Start at a[1] = 0:  n[2] is unchanged because a[1] <= 0.  We print (0,0),(0,1),(0,2).

Next is a[1] = 1:  Since a[1] > c[1][2], n[2] is changed in the loop to min{ n[2],d[1][j] } = 0. We print (1,0).

Finally a[1] = 2:  Since a[1] > c[1][2], n[2] is changed in the loop to min{ n[2],d[1][j] } = 0. (We just did the same thing as before. That's the inefficiency.)  We print (2,0).

Remark: For my application, it can be assumed that c[i][j]=d[i][j].

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Homework?

Comment: The a[i] are the exponents of the possible prime factors of an unknown ideal.  To determine the ideal each tuple is treated as a case and further computations are to be done for each case. Not homework.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to elaborate a little about the purpose of this task.  It's difficult to suggest useful implementation strategies in the absence of any motivating considerations.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting problem.

Note that time is necessarily proportional to the number of tuples that are to be enumerated.  So it isn't possible to improve asymptotically on what you've got.

In terms of length of code, this can't be optimal, not by a long shot.  You simply shouldn't have to code a separate for loop for every single i = 1..m

I may take a whack at the algorithm later; but to make a long story short, the running time will be exponential in m (except for trivial cases where constraints are equal to one.)

Comment: Regarding your remark about code length, the same algorithm can be written more compactly as a recursion in a straightforward way.